# Finding implicit differentiation using power rule.

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Original Function: $(\sin(\pi x)+\cos(\pi y))^2 = 2$ 
Step1: $2(\pi \cos(\pi x) - \pi \sin(\pi y)\frac{dy}{dx})(\sin(\pi x)+\cos(\pi y))$

Step2: $(2\pi \cos(\pi x)-2\pi \sin(\pi y)\frac{dy}{dx})(\sin(\pi x)+\cos(\pi y)$

... and blah blah blah.. 
Igot tired of writing this in mathjax..

and my answer came out to be dy/dx = $\cos(\pi x)$ / $\sin(\pi y)$

did I do this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya you are correct. You can actually use the formula of

$$ dy/dx = -F_x/Fy$$

This might be easier.

Comment: Thanks I will try to re-solve the problem with the formula you posted. My teacher never taught that.

Comment: This is under the topic of partial derivatives. You can search more on that topic if you are interested.